# Retrieving oauth_token and oauth_token_secret (RestSharp on Windows Phone)

Tags: oauth, windows-phone, restsharp

New to OAuth and RestSharp.

I'm building a Windows Phone app, using RestSharp to handle all the OAuth stuff.

```
private void LoginButton_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient(OAuth.Auth.baseurl);
        client.Authenticator = RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(OAuth.Auth.consumerkey, OAuth.Auth.consumersecret);

        var request = new RestRequest("oauth/request_token", Method.POST);

        client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
        {
            var resource = response.Content;

            MessageBox.Show(resource);
            webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(OAuth.Auth.UAuthorise + "?" + resource + "&oauth_callback=http://bing.com"));
        });

    }

private void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Uri.ToString() + " loaded");
        }
```

I'm successfully getting the request token, and then a user is able to log in to the service. webBrowser1 then navigates to bing.com (as defined in the callback url). My question is: what do I do to get the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret? I can *see* them, due to the webBrowser1_LoadCompleted event handler, but how can I extract them to use them in my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the `Navigating` event for the browser control when it redirect back to the callback domain/Uri.
You can then extract the values you're after from from the Uri.